# Pumpandsettle() time out when using --test-randomize-ordering-seed flag but passes without the flag

Tags: flutter, testing, widget

When adding the flag --test-randomize-ordering-seed on running the flutter test pumpandsettle timeout occurs but without the flag, all test cases pass.

The following error was thrown:

```
The following assertion was thrown running a test:
pumpAndSettle timed out

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      WidgetTester.pumpAndSettle.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:673:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
<asynchronous suspension>
(elided one frame from package:stack_trace)
```

Comment: If you're getting a failure with `--test-randomize-ordering-seed`, then that means that your tests are accidentally order-dependent.  It's impossible for anyone to tell what you're doing wrong without seeing code.  If you can't figure it out, I suggest comparing the order of the tests from a successful run against the order of the order of the tests from an unsuccessful run and gradually disabling tests until you can identify the dependency.

Comment: Please post test code.